# Как можно такой затратный код преобразовать в функцию? + плюшки

Tags: php, оптимизация

Здравствуйте! Я новичок в php, буду надеяться на ваше благоразумие. Есть код:

```
     <? if (   (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['english'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['russian'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['polish'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['bulgarian'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['french']))   ){ echo '<div id="stream">
     <div class="tabselect" >

          <div class="tab" style="width: 100%; border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px; position: relative; z-index: 10;">
              English Stream
                  <div class="submenu" style="width: 810px;">
                  <a class="tab" style="width: 100%;text-align:center; padding:0; margin:0;" '.$match['id'].' ,Bulgarian)">Bulgarian Stream</a>
                  <a class="tab" style="width: 100%;text-align:center; padding:0; margin:0;" '.$match['id'].' ,French)">French Stream</a>
                  <a class="tab" style="width: 100%;text-align:center; padding:0; margin:0;" '.$match['id'].' ,Russian)">German Stream</a>
                  <a class="tab" style="width: 100%;text-align:center; padding:0; margin:0;" '.$match['id'].' ,Polish)">Polish Stream</a>
                  </div>
          </div>        
 </div>' ; }elseif (   (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['english'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['russian'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['polish'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['bulgarian'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['french'])) && (!empty($match['english'])) 
     { echo '<div id="mainstream" style="position: relative; z-index:5;">

              <div class="video-container">
              <iframe src="//player.twitch.tv/?channel='.$match['english'].'&autoplay=false" height="480" width="832" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" style="display: inline-block;"></iframe>
              </div>
              <iframe frameborder="1" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="//www.twitch.tv/'.$match['english'].'/chat?popout=" height="550" width="100%" style="display: inline-block; z-index:10; position: relative; float: right;"></iframe>
     </div>
' ;}elseif (   (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['english'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['russian'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['polish'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['bulgarian'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['french'])) && (!empty($match['russian'])) 
     { echo '<div id="mainstream" style="position: relative; z-index:5;">

              <div class="video-container">
              <iframe src="//player.twitch.tv/?channel='.$match['russian'].'&autoplay=false" height="480" width="832" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" style="display: inline-block;"></iframe>
              </div>
              <iframe frameborder="1" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="//www.twitch.tv/'.$match['russian'].'/chat?popout=" height="550" width="100%" style="display: inline-block; z-index:10; position: relative; float: right;"></iframe>
     </div>
' ;}elseif (   (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['english'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['russian'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['polish'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['bulgarian'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['french'])) && (!empty($match['polish'])) 
     { echo '<div id="mainstream" style="position: relative; z-index:5;">

              <div class="video-container">
              <iframe src="//player.twitch.tv/?channel='.$match['polish'].'&autoplay=false" height="480" width="832" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" style="display: inline-block;"></iframe>
              </div>
              <iframe frameborder="1" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="//www.twitch.tv/'.$match['polish'].'/chat?popout=" height="550" width="100%" style="display: inline-block; z-index:10; position: relative; float: right;"></iframe>
     </div>
' ;}elseif (   (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['english'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['russian'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['polish'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['bulgarian'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['french'])) && (!empty($match['french'])) 
     { echo '<div id="mainstream" style="position: relative; z-index:5;">

              <div class="video-container">
              <iframe src="//player.twitch.tv/?channel='.$match['french'].'&autoplay=false" height="480" width="832" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" style="display: inline-block;"></iframe>
              </div>
              <iframe frameborder="1" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="//www.twitch.tv/'.$match['french'].'/chat?popout=" height="550" width="100%" style="display: inline-block; z-index:10; position: relative; float: right;"></iframe>
     </div>
' ;}elseif (   (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['english'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['russian'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['polish'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['bulgarian'])) || (($match['live']) == 1 && !empty($match['french'])) && (!empty($match['bulgarian'])) 
     { echo '<div id="mainstream" style="position: relative; z-index:5;">

              <div class="video-container">
              <iframe src="//player.twitch.tv/?channel='.$match['bulgarian'].'&autoplay=false" height="480" width="832" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" style="display: inline-block;"></iframe>
              </div>
              <iframe frameborder="1" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="//www.twitch.tv/'.$match['bulgarian'].'/chat?popout=" height="550" width="100%" style="display: inline-block; z-index:10; position: relative; float: right;"></iframe>
     </div>
' ;} 

 '</div>'; } ?>
```

Его надо преобразовать в функцию `choseStream()`, в которой будут указаны значения: `<?match['id']?>` и `<?match['english, russian, bulgarian, french etc']` типа `choseStream($match['id'], $match['english'])` и чтоб при вызове функции onclick загружался стрим, пример:

```
`<a class="tab" style="width: 100%;" onclick="choseStream(<?=$match['id']?>,<?=$match['english']?>)">English Stream</a>
<a class="tab" style="width: 100%;" onclick="choseStream(<?=$match['id']?>,<?=$match['russian']?>)">Russian Stream</a>
<a class="tab" style="width: 100%;" onclick="choseStream(<?=$match['id']?>,<?=$match['french']?>)">French Stream</a>
<a class="tab" style="width: 100%;" onclick="choseStream(<?=$match['id']?>,<?=$match['bulgarian']?>)">Bulgarian Stream</a>`
```

Comment: Отделите логику от представления, гуглите MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку вы генерируете текст то встает необходимость в его сокращении, сокращение можно получить тремя путями:

1. Использовать автоматический алгоритм подстановки
2. Использовать циклы
3. Использовать шаблоны

Первый способ используется если есть постоянная закономерность изменений. Например имеем такой текст:

```
word1
word2
word3
word1
word2
word3
```

Как несложно догадаться у нас меняется окончание для слова word от 1 до 3 и эта комбинация циклически повторяется два раза. Значит мы имеем алгоритм:

```
СТАРТ АЛГОРИТМА
  менять окончание от 1 до 3
  повторить 1 раз
КОНЕЦ АЛГОРИТМА
```

Второй способ используется при повторяющемся тексте. Например имеем такой текст.

```
word_word
word_word
word_word
word_word
```

Вместо того что бы печатать четыре раза одно и то же мы можем использовать циклы:

```
СТАРТ АЛГОРИТМА
  запуск цикла который напечатает слово word_word четыре раза
КОНЕЦ АЛГОРИТМА
```

Но тут надо понимать что при повторении бывает так что меняются только какие то элементы. Например имеем такой текст:

```
word_(a)_word_(b)
word_(c)_word_(d)
word_(e)_word_(f)
```

Тут можно применить шаблон с параметром/ми (это **третий** вариант):

```
ШАБЛОН ПАРАМЕТР1 ПАРАМЕТР2
  word_(ПАРАМЕТР1)_word_(ПАРАМЕТР2)
КОНЕЦ ШАБЛОНА
```

Теперь этот шаблон можно запустить три раза с разными параметрами:

```
ШАБЛОН(a, b)
ШАБЛОН(c, d)
ШАБЛОН(e, f)
```

Как видно из примера код значительно сократился.

Нужно добавить что каждый выше перечисленный пример легко реализовать в виде обычных функций.